# How to Find the matched record in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, find

I have a record in my collection and I want to fetch the details of the person whose id is 1. But I am getting the details for 2times instead of 1.

```
    db.mycollection.insert({"person" : [ { "id":1, "details" : { "name" : "Aswini", "Age" : 10 }}, { "id":2, "details" : { "name" : "Mahesh", "Age" : 11}}]})
```

Then running

```
    > db.mycollection.findOne({"person.id":1},{"person.details":1,"_id":0})
```

the result is :

```
    {
        "person" : 
                [
                    {
                        "details" : 
                        {
                         "name" : "Aswini",
                         "Age" : 10
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "details" : 
                        {
                         "name" : "Mahesh",
                         "Age" : 11
                        }
                    }
                ]
    }
```

But I need as follows:

```
    {
    "person" : [
                {
                "details" : {
                            "name" : "Aswini",
                            "Age" : 10
                        }
                }
            ]
    }
```

Don't understand where am making mistake. Please need your help. Am using MongoDB, Java

Answer (score 3):

This is the behavior of filtering multi level embedded document, normally the matching filter would return the whole document, not the subsets.

Usually `positional operator $` used to match the sub documents in `updates`. But the feature is not yet implemented in return specifiers.

There is an outstanding issue already in mongo [Support for positional ($) operator in fields to return specifier](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828). (Please login to vote if you really needed the feature)

So you have to redesgin your schema to handle this, may be like this

```
db.test.insert({"person" : [ { "id":1, "details" : { "name" : "Aswini", "Age" : 10 }}]})
db.test.insert({"person" : [ { "id":2, "details" : { "name" : "Mahesh", "Age" : 11}}]})

db.test.find({"person.id":1},{'person.details':1})
```

Answer (score 0):

`person` is an array. If you want to get first element of this array you should use [$slice](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements)

```
db.mycollection.findOne({"person.id":1},{"person":{$slice:[0,1]},"_id":0})
```

Comment: its wrong. op doesn't want the 1 st element, he want to retrieve the matching sub array irrespective of the position. if the person.id sub doc is in last position above query will not woek

Comment: You are absolutely right. I want the sub array irrespective of its index. Please help if you have any solution am a newbee to mongodb