# Big Data Xml file (file size over 20GB) convert to Json File

Tags: c#, xml, json

I have an XML file. I want to convert it to JSON with C#. However, the XML file is over 20 GB.

I have tried to read XML with XmlReader, then append every node to a JSON file. I wrote the following code:

```
var path = @"c:\result.json";
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true, Encoding.UTF8);
tw.Write("{\"A\":");

using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader("c:\\muslum.xml"))
{
    while (xmlTextReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlTextReader.Name == "A")
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            var v = xmlTextReader.ReadInnerXml();

            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

            tw.Write(json);
        }
    }
}

tw.Write("}");
tw.Close();
```

This code not working. I am getting error while converting json. Is there any best way to perform the conversion?

Comment: Have you looked at XDocument which you can query xml with linq. It will make your task easier

Comment: What's the error? Try to process a smaller file (let's say two nodes) to see what's wrong with that JSON (for example: if your loop produces an array...where is it open/closed?)

Comment: Have you try the solution of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711818/storing-large-xml-in-mongodb (kind of double content)

Comment: Here's one error `@"c:\\result.json"` you mean either `@"c:\result.json"` or `"c:\\result.json"`

Comment: mongo has a max size of 16MB for a document. are you sure you want to convert 20GB to json?

Comment: @I3arnon, I want to use I free and fast database. So I decided to use mongodb. What do you prefer to me.

Comment: do you have schema for this file?

Comment: @vittore Yes I have. Before Importing to db, I is validating with xsd schema.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the following way

- generate classes out of xsd schema using xsd.exe
- open file and read top level ( i e your document level ) tags one by one  (with XmlTextReader or XmlReader)
- serialize each tag into object using generated classes
- deserialize resulting object to json and save to whatever
- consider saving in batches of 1000-2000 tags
- you are right about serialize/deserialize being slow. still doing work in several threads, preferably using TPL will give you good speed. Also consider using json.net serializer, it is really a lot faster than standard ones ( it is standard for web.api though)

I can put some code snippets in the morning if you need them.
We are processing big ( 1-10gigs) files this manner in order to save data to sql server database.

Comment: I thought this. But serialize and deserialize processes take long time. So Importing xml to db get very long time. I asked the  question find the fastest way. I will be happy if you share code snippets. Thanks